# Is it possible to prevent the version of BranchSDK from being included as a KEY value in Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, branch.io

We are using Branch's iOS SDK version `2.2.0`.
And the minimum version of our app is iOS 13, and the Xcode version is 15.2.

Whenever an issue occurs in Firebase Crashlytics, the version of BranchSDK is also included as a KEY value.
Is it possible to prevent `io.branch.sdk.version` from being displayed as a Key in Crashlytics?"

[image]